# Dependence speed up on data size using auto vectorization and sse

Tags: caching, sse, vectorization, icc

I'm trying to speed up some code using auto vectorization from Intel Compiler and using sse.
All computations are transformation some struct node_t to another struct w_t (functions tr() and gen_tr()).
When I try vectorize function gen_tr() it does not produce any effects.

If change data storage format, when each struct component stored in different array of floats, then auto vectorization works well, see function genv_tr().

Function that used sse called ssev_tr (N should divided evenly by 4).

## transform.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

static __inline__ unsigned long getCC(void)
{
    unsigned a, d;
    asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));
    return ((unsigned long)a) | (((unsigned long)d) << 32);
}

typedef struct {
    float x1, x2, x3, x4, x5;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    float w1, w2, w3, w4;
} w_t;

void tr(node_t *n, float c1, float c2, w_t *w)
{
    const float nv = n->x1;
    const float N00T = n->x3 * c1;

    const float n1v = n->x2;
    const float N01T = n->x4 * c2;

    w->w1 = nv  - N00T;
    w->w2 = nv  + N00T;
    w->w3 = n1v - N01T;
    w->w4 = n1v + N01T;
}

__attribute__ ((noinline))
void gen_tr(node_t *n, w_t *w, const int N, float c1, float c2)
{
    int i;
    #pragma vector aligned
    #pragma ivdep
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tr(n + i, c1, c2, w + i);
    }
}

__attribute__ ((noinline))
void genv_tr(float *x1, float *x2, float *x3, float *x4, float *x5, float *w1, float *w2, float *w3, float *w4, const int N, float c1, float c2)
{
    int i;
    #pragma vector aligned
    #pragma ivdep
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        const float N00T = x3[i] * c1;
        const float N01T = x4[i] * c2;

        w1[i] = x1[i] - N00T;
        w2[i] = x1[i] + N00T;
        w3[i] = x2[i] - N01T;
        w4[i] = x2[i] + N01T;
    }
}

__attribute__ ((noinline))
void ssev_tr(float *x1, float *x2, float *x3, float *x4, float *x5, float *w1, float *w2, float *w3, float *w4, const int N, float c1, float c2)
{
    __m128 *ws1 = (__m128*)w1;
    __m128 *ws2 = (__m128*)w2;
    __m128 *ws3 = (__m128*)w3;
    __m128 *ws4 = (__m128*)w4;
    
    __m128 *xs1 = (__m128*)x1;
    __m128 *xs2 = (__m128*)x2;
    __m128 *xs3 = (__m128*)x3;
    __m128 *xs4 = (__m128*)x4;
    
    const __m128 cs1 = _mm_set1_ps(c1);
    const __m128 cs2 = _mm_set1_ps(c2);
    
    int i;
    #pragma vector aligned
    #pragma ivdep
    for (i = 0; i < N / 4; i++) {
        const __m128 N00T = _mm_mul_ps(xs3[i], cs1);
        const __m128 N01T = _mm_mul_ps(xs4[i], cs2);

        ws1[i] = _mm_sub_ps(xs1[i], N00T);
        ws2[i] = _mm_add_ps(xs1[i], N00T);
        ws3[i] = _mm_sub_ps(xs2[i], N01T);
        ws4[i] = _mm_add_ps(xs2[i], N01T);
    }
}

#define test(func) \
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { \
        x[i].x1 = 1.0; \
        x[i].x2 = 2.0; \
        x[i].x3 = 2.0; \
        x[i].x4 = 2.0; \
        x[i].x5 = 2.0; \
    } \
    \
    t1 = getCC(); \
    for (i = 0; i < rep; i++) { \
        func(x, w, n, c1, c2); \
    } \
    t2 = getCC(); \
    printf("\t%f", ((double)(t2 - t1)) / n / rep);

#define test1(func) \
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { \
        x1[i] = 1.0; \
        x2[i] = 2.0; \
        x3[i] = 2.0; \
        x4[i] = 2.0; \
        x5[i] = 2.0; \
    } \
    \
    t1 = getCC(); \
    for (i = 0; i < rep; i++) { \
        func(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, w1, w2, w3, w4, n, c1, c2); \
    } \
    t2 = getCC(); \
    printf("\t%f", ((double)(t2 - t1)) / n / rep);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage %s vector_size\n", argv[0]);
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d", n);
    int rep = 100000000 / n;
    int i;
    int inc = 1;
    float c1 = 2.0, c2 = 1.0;
    unsigned long t1, t2;
    node_t *x = (node_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(node_t));
    w_t *w = (w_t*)malloc(n * sizeof(w_t));
    
    float *x1 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *x2 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *x3 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *x4 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *x5 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    
    float *w1 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *w2 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *w3 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    float *w4 = (float*)malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    
    test(gen_tr);
    test1(genv_tr);
    test1(ssev_tr);
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile options: icc -O3 -Wall -W -vec-report6 transform.c -o transform

Version of icc - 12.1.2, OS - Fedora 16 x86_64, CPU - Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q8200.

Then i run it with different size from 16 to 3000 with step 64, here script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "" > run.log

for ((c=16;c<3000;c+=64))
do
./transform $c | tee -a run.log
done
```

Here some result of work this script (size, gen_tr, genv_tr, ssev_tr), all times shown per one array element:

```
16      7.710743        3.168577        3.253829
272     7.166493        1.983918        2.618569
528     7.121866        1.920195        2.567109
784     7.115007        1.899451        2.549645
1040    8.104026        2.481062        2.944317
1296    8.137537        5.105032        5.104614
1552    8.118534        5.068812        5.064211
1808    8.138309        5.077831        5.085015
2064    8.149699        5.107503        5.069958
2320    8.164556        5.080981        5.099313
2576    8.151524        5.086056        5.089294
2832    8.212946        5.061927        5.072261
```

why it is so significant change about size 1000 when using vectorized version of function? Does it because of cache miss? Is it possible to save same speed on all data ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 8 float arrays. When they are of size 1000, your test is manipulating about 32kB of data. Even though your L1 cache is probably a bit larger (64kB), the L1 cache is likely unable to hold all the 32kB data at the same time due to associativity.

Your test iterates, processing the same data over and over again. Consider the two cases:

- **Size = 528**: The 8 arrays conveniently fit into the L1 cache. Each test iteration (except for the first one) has fast access to the data.
- **Size = 1268**: The 8 arrays do not fit into the L1 cache at the same time. Each test iteration keeps evicting the data from L1, so effectively all reads and writes go to L2.

So the jump at input size 1000 is partly an artifact of your test, but not entirely. In the real world, if you already happen to have all the data you need in the L1 cache, genv_tr will be really fast. But on inputs of size >1000, all the inputs simply do not fit into the L1 cache, so some accesses will definitely go to L2.